# Filtering by multiple selected classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I've created a Multiple Checkbox Filter

The idea is to select among categories and filter the elements that have AT LEAST one of those categories

At the moment, it's filtering but showing the elements that have ALL of the categories

This is what I'm using:

```
function run() {
    $("div").hide();
    choice = "";
    $(":checked").each(function() {
       choice += "." + this.id;
    });
    if (choice) 
        $("div" + choice).show();
};
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ynmesqj7/) is a fiddle to show you how it works.

How can I show the elements that have at least one of the classes checked then?

Comment: In the each loop, simply call `$("." + this.id).show();` and remove the code after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show them in forEach loop

```
function run() {
    $("div").hide();
    const checked = $(":checked")
    if (checked.length === 0) {
        return $("div").show();
    }
    checked.each(function() {
        $("div." + this.id).show();
    });
};
```

Comment: `$("#" + this.id).show();` performs faster than `div.#id`

Comment: @Cue true, but the elements being targeted have `class` attributes, not `id`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my eyes aren’t working today. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I edited answer so you can show every if none inputs are checked